# Use alt text for linked image

Tags: javascript, html, image, seo, alt

For images for my website I always use 1 thumbnail and 1 full size image.

I'd very much like to apply alt text for my full size images, but I don't know how, since the full size image is linked with `<a>` and isn't an `<img>` object.
It's for SEO reasons, so that the full size images will be more easily searchable through Google image search.

How can I apply alt text for my full size images? I'm using highslide for displaying images at the moment, but perhaps there's another alternative that can give me what I'm looking for.

This is the site that I'm referring to:
http://www.easterislandtraveling.com/easter-island/gallery/

Comment: I am bit confused...The links given to thumbnails go directly to image file. Do you want them to go to an HTML page, and that page should bear the full image?

Comment: In my opinion you should use the ALT tag to provide useful information for Google. Otherwise Google will struggle to understand what the image actually is. Have a read of what [Google say](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114016).

Comment: Looking at the source for highslide.config.js, we can see something interesting on line10 (hs.captionEval = 'this.a.title';) This tells me that the framework is setup to grab attributes from the *something* You could try to modify this line to see if you can grab another attribute. If so, you could probably extend it so it will apply the alt attribute as found on the <a> tag.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys!

anishsane: No, I'd like for the photos to still get maximized on the same page. With the current solution, that's what they do, but the full size images don't get an alt tag, since they're called through the highslide javascript through an <a> tag.
Adam: That's what I'm trying to do.
enhzflep: that's interesting! Something like this is what I'm looking for. If we do Inspect Element at the full size image, we can see that a <img>-tag is generated (obviously), but it doesn't contain an alt tag - only <title>, which doesn't do me much good.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but just a thought. Can you get the alt text from the thumbnail and add it to the image alt that is generated. I think the function that does this is in the `highslide-full.js` and inside the function `hs.Expander = function(a, params, custom, contentType)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a question about the highslide library, which you are using to create the  tags when the thumbnails are clicked. Checking the documentation at http://highslide.com/ref/ there doesn't seem to be an easy way of controlling the alt text using that library. You could use one of the events to manipulate the generated HTML yourself, perhaps onBeforeExpand.

If you are only doing this for SEO reasons, then I would suggest it is unnecessary. Doing a Google image search for the alt text of your first image shows that Google are already indexing the higher resolution version. Clicking 'visit page' takes you to the page you gave in your question. See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Rano+Raraku+moai+factory+with+man+sitting%22+site:easterisland.travel&tbm=isch

Answer (score -1):

Could you use the `title` attribute on the `<a>` tag instead?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: Unfortunately no, since that info won't pass onto the alt tag of the <img>, and so Google wouldn't have any info about what the image contains.